# What can delay the establishment of new connections with NetTcpBinding?

Tags: .net, wcf, net.tcp

We have a WCF service and sometimes, **requests done via newly established channels take between 3 and 8 seconds**, even though concurrent requests that use pooled channels are processed instantaneously. In other words, the system is responsive in general.

The number of concurrently processed requests at that time is less than 10, much lower than any configured upper limit, and the number of concurrent sessions shouldn't be hitting any limit either. This is how the service is set up:

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue;

binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
binding.MaxConnections = 256;

host.AddServiceEndpoint(contract, binding, address);
host.Description.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ServiceDebugBehavior));
host.Description.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ServiceMetadataBehavior));
host.Description.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ServiceThrottlingBehavior));
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = false });
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceThrottlingBehavior { MaxConcurrentCalls = 256, MaxConcurrentSessions = 1000, MaxConcurrentInstances = 1000 });

host.Open();
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried load testing a system similar to what we have in production, and was able to get connection establishment to take more than 5 seconds, by establishing about 100 connections and letting each of them do WCF calls that just `Thread.Sleep(20ms)` on the server, in an endless loop.

Method executions on newly created channels gradually went up to more than 5 seconds, while the same methods executed on existing channels took only up to 500 milliseconds.

It turned out that **the server, which has 4 cpu cores, was always invoking the method in 1 of only 4 to 7 different threads** (overwhelmingly in 1 of 4 threads, but occasionally 3 other threads got used as well). That doesn't give you a lot of parallelism, which is especially useful, if those methods are waiting on IO (as simulated by the call to Sleep()).

I tried `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(40, 40)`, but that didn't help, I guess due to a [bug in .net 3.5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976898).

So **I tried .net 4, and even without calling SetMinThreads, the problems went away.** I noticed that the **method on the server is called from many more different threads now**, and the number of actually used IO Completion Port Threads grows as necessary as well.

**N.B.** In fact, there's something similar to this in MS' knowledge base: [WCF service may scale up slowly under load](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2538826) It presents a workaround to make WCF execute on worker threads instead of IO threads, which, according to that article, may enter

> a state where it cannot create threads quickly enough to immediately handle a burst of requests. The response time increases unexpectedly as new threads are created at a rate of 1 per 500ms.

That's bad enough, in my case however, no new IO threads were created at all, at least not in the tens of seconds of my tests.